# What is the right way to define annotation for DECIMAL type in Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a column in my table with `DECIMAL(19,4)` and I'm creating my Entity for a project, what is the right way to define this field? What **precision** and **scale** parameters means in [Doctrine Annotations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html)?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The precision is the number of digits in the number. For example, 123456.78 has a precision of 8.

Scale is the is the maximum number of decimal places. 123456.78 has a scale of 2.

`DECIMAL(19,4)` would allow 19 total digits, with four decimal places.

The annotation for that would be:

```
@Column(type="decimal", precision=19, scale=4)
```