# How to set a decimal in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fieldtype

I've been trying to simply set a field type to a decimal between 0 and 1 however no matter the configuration I have, doctrine always rounds my decimal from my form field to the nearest whole number.

My entity:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @Assert\Range(
 * min=0,
 * max=1,
 * minMessage = "this must be greater than or equal to 0.",
 * maxMessage = "this must be less than or equal to 1."
 * )
 * @ORM\Column(name="nuetu", type="decimal", precision=2, scale=1, nullable=true)
 */
private $nuetu;
```

My Field Type:

```
        ->add('nuetu', 'integer', array(
            'scale' => 1,
            'attr' => array(
                'min' => 0,
                'max' => 1,
                'step' => '.1',
            ),
            'label' => 'Lef a nuetu',
            'required' => false,
        ))
```

My Twig:

```
{{ form_row(form.nuetu, {'type': 'number'}) }}
```

I've also tried `{{ form_row(form.nuetu) }}` & without using `assert` and without declaring `precision` or `scale` in my entity annotations.

My goal is to persist the number to the database as (0.3 or 0.8).

I've looked at these questions but I have been unsuccessful:

[What is the right way to define annotation for DECIMAL type in Doctrine2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512612/what-is-the-right-way-to-define-annotation-for-decimal-type-in-doctrine2)

[Rounded decimal in edit form Symfony2 + Doctrine2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979090/rounded-decimal-in-edit-form-symfony2-doctrine2)

http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/integer.html

http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/number.html#scale

Comment: Your Field Type is specifying an `integer` type. You need to change to `number` type.

Answer (score 4):

At last, in Symfony 4, you need put the option HTML5 on true, if do not, the filed be a text type....
`'html5' => true`

Answer (score 3):

Integer is not a decimal. Use number like ehymel mentioned:

```
->add('nuetu', NumberType::class, array(
    'scale' => 1,
    'attr' => array(
        'min' => 0,
        'max' => 1,
        'step' => '.1',
    ),
    'label' => 'Lef a nuetu',
    'required' => false,
))
```

The above should work.